# Setting the last element of an array to a separate String and then removing said element

Tags: javascript, html, arraylist

I have an array that could have between 1 and 11 elements. I want to remove the last element and make it a new string, then set the rest of the arraylist to a collective string. The following code isn't working...Do I need to include an if else incase the arraylist has only one element? (I know I do, I'm wondering if that would cause the script not to be executed at all)

```
var finaling = checked[checked.length].toString();
    checked.splice(checked[checked.length]);
    checked.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it...

> I want to remove the last element...

```
checked.pop();
```

> ...and make it a new string...

```
checked.push('new string');
// or skip the above `pop()`
checked[checked.length - 1] = 'new string';
```

> ...then set the rest of the arraylist to a collective string.

```
checked = checked + '';
```

The default `toString()` of an array will join the elements with a `','`. If you want to use a different joining character, use `join()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but this should do it:

```
var lastElementInArray = checked.splice(checked.length-1)[0].toString();
var stringOfChecked = checked.toString();
```

Or if you want to remove the last element of an array and return a string representing the new array:

```
checked.splice(checked.length-1, 1);
var finaling = checked.toString();
```

Something to note: `array.splice()` returns an array of elements; if you only have one element in it and you want that actual element, you'll want to use `array.splice(...)[0]`.

Comment: Hmm...why would it be the length minus one? Wouldn't the length be the last element?

Comment: Remember that arrays in Javascript are 0-indexed, such that an array with three elements has a length of three but elements at positions 0, 1, and 2. Therefore the last element is the length of the array minus 1.